# How to match different classes and attributes simultaneously using find_all in beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, attributes, tags, findall

I want to create an element Result Set that would contain all entries matching 2 conditions: their attribute under one class would be "col1" and their attribute under another class would be "10.10". (A set as an intersection of two result sets)

Currently I am able to create two separate result sets:

```
result1 = soup.find_all("textline", {"type" : "col1"}) #gives 600 results
result2 = soup.find_all("font", {"size" : "10.10"}) #gives 100 results
```

I would like to create a result set, in which only the entries satisfying both conditions would be included (intersection).

I tried putting both properties in a list, but it simply adds the results together

```
result = soup.find_all(["textline", {"type" : "col1"}, "font", { "size" : "10.10"}]) #gives 700 results
```

I also tried writing a for-loop, but it returns a list of the same length as result1 (and not the intersection of result1 and result2)

```
a= []
for i in soup.find_all("textline", {"type" : "col1"}):
    result = i.find_all("font", { "size" : "10.10"})
    a.append(result)
```

Comment: Could you share a pair of examples of the tag elements you are trying to parse?

Comment: <textline bbox="81.600,450.647,178.692,460.547" type="col1"><font face="Times-Italic" size="9.900">XeAchKit-Erlsiiirtntg.  </font></textline>
<textline bbox="57.800,410.347,151.488,420.391" type="col1"><font face="Times-Roman" size="10.10">1.  Geographical entities  </font></textline>

Comment: So basically I would like to parse the text of the second element "1.Geographical entities", because it's textline type="col1" and font size = "10.10", but not the first one "XeAchKit-Erlsiiirtntg", because it's font size= "9.900" (although the type is still "col1")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use [`.select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """<textline bbox="81.600,450.647,178.692,460.547" type="col1"><font face="Times-Italic" size="9.900">XeAchKit-Erlsiiirtntg. </font></textline> <textline bbox="57.800,410.347,151.488,420.391" type="col1"><font face="Times-Roman" size="10.10">1. Geographical entities </font></textline> """
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
soup.select('textline[type="Col1"] font[size="10.10"]')
```

output:

```
[<font face="Times-Roman" size="10.10">1. Geographical entities </font>]
```